# FFmpeg image sequence to video with variable image durations

Tags: ffmpeg

I have been looking for a way to convert a sequence of PNGs to a video. There are ways to do that using the CONCAT function within FFmpeg and using a script.
The problem is that I want to show certain images longer than others. And I need it to be accurate. I can set a duration (in seconds) in the script file. But I need it to be frame-accurate. So far I have not been successful.
    
    **This is what I want to make:**

- Quicktime video with transparancy *(Prores4444 or other codec that supports transparancy + alpha channel)*
- 25fps

**This is what I have:** *[ TimecodeIn - TimecodeOut in destination video ]*

- img001.png [0:00:05:10 - 0:00:07:24]
- img002.png [0:00:09:02 - 0:00:12:11]
- img003.png [0:00:15:00 - 0:00:17:20]
- ...
- img120.png [0:17:03:11 - 0:17:07:01]

Of course this is not the format of the script file. Just an idea about what kind of data I am dealing with. The PNG-imagefiles are subtitles I generate elsewhere in my application. I would like to be able to export the subtitles as a transparent movie that I can easily import in my video editing software.
    
I also have been thinking of using blank transparent images I will use as spacers, between the actual subtitle images.

Comment: What command did you try?

Comment: You can define a framerate, and then create N images that will appear at that framerate. To get certain images to appear longer, duplicate the same image file multiple times so that the indicated frame will appear for longer. For example, if Frame27.png should last for 3 frames at 10 fps then copy that same image to Frame28.png and Frame29.png.

Comment: Sounds like I would have to generate an image sequence animation. With a bunch of duplicated frames.

Answer (score -1):

After looking around I think this might help:
On the [FFMPEG site](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Slideshow) they explain about making a timed slideshow

In the Concat demuxer section they talk about making a slideshow, based on a text file, with references to the image files and the duration of the image.
So, I create all the PNG images I need. These images have the subtitle text. Each image holds one subtitle page.
For the moments I want to hide the subtitle, I use a blank PNG.

I generate a text file as explained on the FFMPEG website.
This text file will reference to all the PNGs. For the duration I just calculate the outcue - incue. Easy... I think...

Comment: not the place for comments. Out of curiosity, did you find an answer?